# Improve Android Emulator Performance on Windows 7 x64

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

I'm running on Eclipse Helios on Windows 7 x64. I have a Core 2 Duo 2.0 Ghz with 4.0 GB which I think should be enough, since I've never have any performance problems with developing tools.

When I run my first app on the Android Emulator (both 2.3.3 and 3.0) it took at least 5 minutes to load the OS and at first it didn't even run the HelloAndroid app. Even when I managed to run the application, the performance was unbareable.

The strange things is that is not a OS performance issue. This is the CPU and Memory status while executing:

[image: CPUPerformanceWhileRunning]

I've tryed various things to improve the performance, but no major improvement is shown. I think I'm missing something.

Things I have tryed:

On AVD Manager

1. Device RAM size to 512.
2. Resolution to 640 x 480.
3. Snapshot enabled.

On Project preferences\Android

1. \Launch\ -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim -cache ./cache -avd Android3

Things I can't tryed:
- Deploying on a device (don't have any).

By the way, I've had the same problem on a MAC Mini 2.66 Ghz 2 GB but these settings made the difference.

Anyone can give any tips to improve this lame performance?.

Comment: Yeah, it does take some time to load up the simulator. Just don't close it afterwards! You can still build apps while it's open!

Comment: Try upping the RAM to 1024, but I do most of my debugging on devices for this reason.

Comment: The problem is that even when the emulator is loaded (when it does), it runs extremely slow.

Comment: I have increased the RAM to 1024 and even more...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you are not alone on this.

There doesn't seem to be a good solution, but a few tips:

- Start the AVD directly, not through the IDE
- Leave the AVD running instead of closing/restarting when you change code
- Debug on a real device. Yes, you lose testing on multiple versions and resolutions, but for many of us, it's the only bearable solution.

Hope this helps a bit...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the emulator would freeze at "android_". I fixed it by changing the compatibility mode on emulator.exe to "Windows 7". Now it's always slow, but it's running.

Answer (score 1):

Open taskmanager and right click on emlulator-arm.exe (*32), klick processor affinity (affiniteit instellen) and select  (if you want ofcource) or just select te cores you want to use. Increases the performance a lot for me (with eight threads available)!

Answer (score 0):

My performance issue was mainly caused by the resolution of the Emulator. I set the resolution to one of the default values of the emulator resolution and it's working much better. I wouldn't say it works as good as the iPhone simulator, but I can work with.